# Is there any C++ counterpart for Borland C++ Builder 5's dir.h header?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, c++builder-5

I need to adapt a file written in Borland C++ Builder 5 to be usable in MS Visual Studio 2022. One of the files heavily utilizes the `dir.h` library, which, as far as I can tell, is a C library exclusive to Builder. The source files are available, however they have a lot of dependencies and, as I've mentioned, are written in C. I have searched the Internet for a substitute, unfortunately to no avail. Does a similar library exist for C++? Or do I have to re-write the file (which is pretty big) using e.g. `std::filesystem`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions in [`dir.h`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Dir.h_Index) are mapping quite direct to Win32 API calls of [`fileapi.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/). You could use this header for a quick port.

For a modernization, it might be the best idea to re-write the code using `std::filesystem`. There is hardly any sensible C++ library with such a C-like API.

Well, there are the modernized Embarcadero API-calls in [`System.SysUtils.hpp`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils), but they are still no modern C++, and they are only available in their ecosystem.